# PHP Download Script

Tags: php, download

[edited] I am trying to make a script that downloads a file, the problem is that i am accesing a page(from a server on the network) that generates that file (opens a download window). Is there a way I can get that file witought that pop-up in php? NOTE: I cannot modify the generating page... It is an excel file. The application is called Cognos. I managed with opera to see page variables parsed so I can get to the download page but I must make that download in a folder without the download pop-up

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you mean how can you get it using PHP on the server side or the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a download with headers.

```
// Define the path to file
$file = file_get_contents('path/to/file_creating_script.php');

// Set headers
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=RandomFileName");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

// Read the file from disk
echo $file;
```

I haven't tested this version of the script though.

Comment: Even if it is generated? So for the variable $file I can give the url and variables? Where is it saved?

Comment: For the $file variable you need to define the actual location of the file in the filesystem.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php works with URL wrappers also (it'll read the contets of the file), edited main post.

Comment: It`s Cognos(from IBM), it generates statistics